# Oracle PL-SQL "Regular expression" to replace each "(space)and(space)" with ',' in a string

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, regular-expression

I have a string like this `x=y and g=h and u=1` and I need to replace each `(space)and(space)` with `,`. I'm using the powerful `regular_expression` for this but it does not give me the desired result.

```
select regexp_replace('x=y and g=h and u=1','(^[[:space:]]*)AND(^[[:space:]]*)', ',')
from dual;
```

I was wondering if you could help me out here. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is always exactly one space either side of a lowercase `and`, then you don't need `regexp_replace` as plain old `replace` will do it:

```
with demo (str) as
      ( select 'x=y and g=h and u=1' from dual )
select str
     , replace(str, ' and ', ',') as plain_replace
from   demo;

STR                 PLAIN_REPLACE
------------------- -------------------
x=y and g=h and u=1 x=y,g=h,u=1
```

A regex is needed if the number of spaces can vary:

```
with demo (str) as
      ( select 'x=y  and g=h and   u=1' from dual )
select str
     , replace(str, ' and ', ',') as plain_replace
     , regexp_replace(str, '\s+and\s+', ',') as one_or_more_spaces
from   demo;
```

```
STR                     PLAIN_REPLACE          ONE_OR_MORE_SPACES
----------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------------
x=y  and g=h and   u=1  x=y ,g=h,  u=1         x=y,g=h,u=1
```

The `+` means *one or more*, in contrast to `*` which means *zero or more*. For example I assume you don't want `Band in Spandex` replaced with `B,in Sp,ex`.

To be on the safe side, I've used the [Perl-style](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Perl-influenced-Extensions-in-Oracle-Regular-Expressions.html) `\s` (whitespace) operator rather than a literal space character, as this will also match any tab characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_replace('x=y and g=h and u=1','([[:space:]]*)and([[:space:]]*)', ',')
from dual;

REGEXP_REPL
-----------
x=y,g=h,u=1
```